# SQL Server Having clause not filtering as expected with float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fairly simple subquery here. The intention is to identify employees with less than 40 hours logged for a weeks worth dataset. But every once in a while an employee with an apparent 40 hours will sneak into the view. The data behind it uses float with high precision and I try my best to first round each individual entry to two decimal places then sum all entries up grouped by employee. I even tried < 39.999 and I still get an employee with 40 hours. In fact, if taking the data as is, this employee actually has 40.0000002980232 - more than 40 so I suspect this issue has nothing to do with rounding errors and more to do with syntax. Can anyone figure out why this statement keeps bringing in rows that violate the HAVING clause?

```
    create table #thisweek ([hours] float, time_user varchar(100))

insert into #thisweek values
(1.58000004291534,  'john.doe'),
(4.32000017166138,  'john.doe'),
(0.620000004768372, 'john.doe'),
(1, 'john.doe'),
(0.680000007152557, 'john.doe'),
(2, 'john.doe'),
(2, 'john.doe'),
(3, 'john.doe'),
(0.790000021457672, 'john.doe'),
(3, 'john.doe'),
(2, 'john.doe'),
(1, 'john.doe'),
(3.32999992370605,  'john.doe'),
(2, 'john.doe'),
(4.42000007629395,  'john.doe'),
(1.33000004291534,  'john.doe'),
(0.579999983310699, 'john.doe'),
(3.29999995231628,  'john.doe'),
(2.1800000667572,   'john.doe'),
(0.620000004768372, 'john.doe'),
(0.25,  'john.doe')

select sum(hours) from #thisweek group by time_user
/* 40.0000002980232 */
/* Test: Nothing should come up since employee John Doe has 40 hours */
select sum(Round(hours,2)) hours /*<--- this is the same value as below*/, time_user

from

#thisweek

group by time_user
having sum(Round(hours,2)) < 40  /* how is 40 < 40? */
```

Comment: Please reduce this down to an [mcve]. Provide inputs, expected output(s), and just the query parts necessary to duplicate the behavior (ie. if `maxdate` has nothing to do with the problem then omit it, less is more).

Comment: not sure what you mean. The query is about as simple as it gets

Comment: why are you converting to int at all in the having?  and what data type is hours?  I'm going to guess float. and cringe.

Comment: Did you visit the link? [mcve]. Read through that, provide the DDL, the input (ie. existing data), and the expected output, (the actual output should be able to be reproduced with the above). Without those parts you will get answers like "try this" and "maybe this will work" and "its probably this" because you are the only one that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Give me a sec and I'll do you one better Igor and provide a dataset that I'm having problems with

Comment: Sample data goes a long way, which is probably what @Igor was getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools are lying to you when they return returns '40'. Convert style 2 returns 16 digits:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), SUM(ROUND(hours, 2)), 2) FROM #thisWeek
```

> 3.999999999999999e+001

<del>When you round before summing you are accumulating error versus the original numbers. Some will round up, some will round down. In this case the round down error is larger than round up error, enough to push the sum of the rounded numbers below 40, but it was hard to see because the too was rounding the final result.</del>

I am not convinced that the issue is more rounding down than rounding up, since other people are reporting correct behavior if the rounded value is cast to a decimal prior to summing. In any case the having is working "correctly" but you could not see that due to the display tools rounding the result to an even 40.

Comment: This answer is the most glaring illustration of the problem under the hood. Also taking @chrisuae 's answer into consideration I elected to convert the float to decimal first: having sum(Round(convert(decimal(38,10),hours),2)) < 40. I think the moral of the day is: If you see float, run!

Answer (score 2):

Using float for hours does not seem appropriate as mentioned by [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288205/1043031), but if you must use a `float`, you will need to avoid the [Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) function due to the data type of the return value using float.  An equivalent way to round the values to 2 decimal places would be `cast( hours * 100 + .5  as int) / 100.00`, so your query could be:

```
select sum(cast( hours * 100 + .5  as int) / 100.00) as hours, time_user
from #thisweek
group by time_user
having sum(hours) < 40
```

Comment: Can you explain why float doesn't work with round? I believe you are right. decimal(38,20) does not exhibit the same behavior but I would like more information on why.

Comment: The return type of the round function is also float, so the Sum function is working on floats.  If you use `cast( round(hours,2) as DECIMAL(10,4))` this will also work as the Sum function is working with fixed point data instead of floating point.

Answer (score 1):

I figure if you compare with a decimal value your query will works

```
 select sum(Round(hours,2)) hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate

    from

    #thisweek2

    group by time_user
    having  sum(Round(hours,2)) < 40.0
```

Comment: You don't even need `ROUND`.

Comment: You need to Roud because the RAW value is greater than 40.0. If you use the Floor function, you must compare less than or equal to because  it is an integer compare

Comment: Don't understand what you trying to say here. In any case I have run the OP's example without the round and record is not returned.

Comment: Considering: 
[ RAW Value = 40.0000002980232 (float point)  ]
[ sum(Round(hours,2)) = 39.999999999999999 (float point)  ]
[ Floor(sum(hours,2)) = 40 (int)  ]

If you compare:

[ 40.0000002980232 < 40. You will get zero registers ]    
[ 39.999999999999999 < 40. You will get one register ] 
[ 40 < 40.0 You will get zero registers    ]

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that this IS a rounding error.  When I make this modification to the first query in your example:

```
select convert(int,sum(Round(hours,2))) from #thisweek group by time_user
```

I get 39.   And 39 < 40.  So SQL is handling your HAVING clause correctly.

Comment: This is true. And the convert int thing is something I tried today to make it work and it just makes it worse so I'm gonna erase it from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Solve your problem at the source.  Instead of:

```
create table #thisweek (
    [hours] float,
    time_user varchar(100)
)
```

Use the appropriate data type:

```
create table #thisweek (
    [hours] decimal(10, 4),
    time_user varchar(100)
)
```

Don't use `float`.  Use fixed-point arithmetic.  Most of your decimal places are not important -- are you really measuring work times to fractions of a second?  Even 4 decimal places is probably overkill -- that is to within about 0.3 seconds.

The rest of the code will work, but it is more simply written as:

```
select sum(hours) as hours, time_user
from #thisweek
group by time_user
having sum(hours) < 40;
```

Comment: I agree with you completely. Just so everyone knows, I didn't write the table. I just take care of it. I guess it may be possible for me to fix this unholy precision. But academically it still doesn't make sense to me that  I could get the value 40 in the data then test the same value against the number 40 and get a different result. I amended the OP.

Comment: @jollarvia . . . It makes perfect sense if you understand how floating point arithmetic works and understand that the order of operations is indeterminate in a `SUM()`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a methodology for figuring this out.

First , you know there is at least one bad record, so isolate the data just for that one by adding a where condition just for this user and removing the having condition.

Then build the query step by step until you see where it goes off the rails. Something like:

```
select *
from
#thisweek2
where time_user = 1234

select hours , time_user
from
#thisweek2
where time_user = 1234

select hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate
from
#thisweek2
where time_user = 1234
group by hours, time_user

select Round(hours,2) hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate
from
#thisweek2
group by  Round(hours,2),time_user
having convert(int,sum(Round(hours,2))) < 40

select sum(Round(hours,2)) hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate
from
#thisweek2
group by time_user
where time_user = 1234

select sum(Round(hours,2)) hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate
from
#thisweek2
group by time_user
having sum(hours) < 40


select sum(Round(hours,2)) hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate
from
#thisweek2
group by time_user
having sum(Round(hours,2)) < 40


select sum(Round(hours,2)) hours, time_user,  MAX(cdate) maxdate
from
#thisweek2
group by time_user
having convert(int,sum(Round(hours,2))) < 40
```

for the early queries not using sum, manually add up your results.